# How to Migrate from Centos6.10 to Ubuntu20LTS

Tags: centos6, ubuntu-20.04, migrate

Hello I am trying to Migrate my centos that runs a gocd server to ubuntu any one know the process or steps.

Comment: this should be at serverfault.com... based on the docs https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/install/server/linux.html, you only need to install the gocd in new ubuntu box, then backup the DB also config, then restore it to the new server... same config, same DB, same value.

Comment: Refer the files to https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/install/server/linux.html#location-of-gocd-server-files if the old ones use the same artifact location...

Comment: Thank you @BenyaminLimanto I'm new to all this so when i transfer the backup how do i restore it

Comment: You need to put the backup data on the same artefact location as the docs description, then restore the database, and check the config file, then you are good to go...